# Dualboot Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 on UEFI Unable to Boot to Ubuntu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, uefi

Here is the layout of my disk:

- /dev/sda1 (EFI partition)
- /dev/sda2 (Recovery partition)
- /dev/sda3
- /dev/sda4 (Windows 7 partition -- boot)
- /dev/sda5 (/boot)
- /dev/sda6 (swap)
- /dev/sda7 (/)

I have been trying to use windows boot manager to manage the boot between windows 7 and windows 8. The laptop came with windows 8 (UEFI GPT) and I installed windows 7 into the partition where windows 8 used to reside. I am pretty sure that it just boots into that partition (sda4). I then followed [this](http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/11/05/dual-boot-windows-8-and-ubuntu-12-10-on-uefi-hardware/2/) guide to try to get linux to boot from the windows boot manager. However, when I get to the selection menu and I select the Ubuntu choice, I get a "Windows failed to start" error and it asks me to insert the windows repair disc to repair it. If I select the windows choice, it boots into Windows 7 just fine.

Any ideas of how to point the boot to the linux boot to get Ubuntu to boot up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the 1st paragraph of the Ubuntu Community Documentation about UEFI: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) Given your setup, installing it from Windows may be necessary, and unfortunately, there's no installation script for that scenario, so you'll need to do so manually. When you install, set up the ext4fs driver (assuming that's what you're using on the Linux /boot partition). With any luck, rEFInd will boot either Windows or GRUB, which will then boot Linux. With the ext4fs driver installed, there should also be at least one entry to boot Linux directly (bypassing GRUB), but it/they won't work until you create a `/boot/refind_linux.conf` file with your Linux options. You can do this by running the `mkrlconf.sh` script that comes with rEFInd. If you can't get into Linux via GRUB, you may be able to get the direct-boot entry to work by hitting F2 or Insert twice, which will open an editor in which you can type extra kernel options:

```
ro root=/dev/sda7
```